# How could I make this function work and implement it to multiple IF statements?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: Picture of Rows and Columns of Project]

TLDR: I'm having issues with my `IF(AND(OR)))` function when I add it to my nested `IF` statement. It only returns `FALSE` and 1 equation instead of both equations, I also need to incorporate the same function to the values "Hybrid" and "Escort" to display time in `HH:MM:SS`.

I am currently working on a big project for a video game `rn` with a friend of mine. I have ok knowledge with functions and how to work with a spreadsheet (by FAR not the best though). I've come across an issue regarding my `IF` functions. I got it to work how I wanted to but I'm having issues with one of the `IF` statements in particular. I also need to add the same function to the Values "Control" and "Escort".
Basically: In cell `M2` I want it to display the `TRUE` duration of the match; the game time shown in in-game reports is off due to scoreboard and post round info and varies between the different map types `(Control, Hybrid, Escort, Flashpoint, Push)`. I wrote my `IF`'s statement (below), and it works for every game type `EXCEPT` "Control," unless the scorelind is set to 2-1 or 1-2, it always returns `FALSE`:

```
=IFS(AND(OR(I2 = 1,J2  = 1),G2 = "Control"), (L2 - 80)/(24*60*60), (L2 - 40)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Flashpoint", (L2 - 0)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Hybrid", (L2 - 20)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Push", (L2 - 10)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Escort", (L2 - 30)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Selection", "0:00:00"))))))
```

My thought process was:

> Write an IF function to check for gamemode type (G2)
> Subtract the amount of time loss due to post round info (L2 - x) (where "x" is time in seconds)
> then divide that by 24*60*60 to get my TRUE time played (that was the only way I knew of to get my HH:MM:SS)
> For example : =IF(G2 = "Push", (L2 - 10)/(24*60*60))
> So back to the issue at hand, the time loss for the "Control" gamemode depends on the scoreline: First to 2 map wins. So I wrote an IF(AND(OR))) function for that and it worked on its own:

```
=IF(AND(OR(I2 = 1, J2 = 1),G2 = "Control"), (L2 - 40)/(24*60*60),(L2 - 80)/(24*60*60))
```

When I tried to implement it into my nested `IF` function and it kept giving me this issue: "Wrong number of arguments to `IF`. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

[Here is an example page of my project that I copied over:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xo0FGdHUikHt8YiJncvWVS7Y5IwpzXQY_7rj1V9QwRw/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried making my original code into an `IF`'s statment starting with the `IF(AND(OR)))` function. it got me closer to what I wanted but only returned FALSE and not my other equation. It works when its by itself, but when added to nested `IF` function it fails every time.

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
=IF(G2 = "Flashpoint", (L2 - 0)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Hybrid", (L2 - 20)/(24*60*60), IF(AND(OR(I2 = 1,J2  = 1),G2 = "Control"), (L2 - 80)/(24*60*60), (L2 - 40)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Push", (L2 - 10)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Escort", (L2 - 30)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Selection", "0:00:00"))))))
```

MODIFIED CODE:

```
only returns FALSE and 1 equation instead of both equations i wrote
=IFS(AND(OR(I2 = 1,J2  = 1),G2 = "Control"), (L2 - 80)/(24*60*60), (L2 - 40)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Flashpoint", (L2 - 0)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Hybrid", (L2 - 20)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Push", (L2 - 10)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Escort", (L2 - 30)/(24*60*60), IF(G2 = "Selection", "0:00:00"))))))
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 according to the [example page](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xo0FGdHUikHt8YiJncvWVS7Y5IwpzXQY_7rj1V9QwRw/edit?pli=1#gid=0) provided by OP, I'd say it's [Google Sheet Functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en).

Comment: Yeah @mkrieger1, its google sheet functions

Comment: The question is [TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR), but it seems your are mixing the functions: [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en) and [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: As I understand it, the focus is on the formula in cell M2 (and below); however the raw data includes results for only two matches. The `IFS` statement contains specific adjustments to the elapsed time depending on the "Gamemode Type" and, _in some cases_, win-loss results are also into account. Would you please edit your question to provide a definitive table of each "Gamemode Type" time adjustment AND win-loss ratio results (if applicable). Would you also include sample data for each of these combinations as well as the expected outcome for each combination.